# RS485 unmatched line - what will be the impact?

Tags: rs485, impedance-matching, balanced, unbalanced

I am doing an experiment where I have a computer with an rs485 transceiver on it and data rate of 1Mbs.
an rs485 30m long with Z0 of 120ohm (also have one with Z0 100ohm).
at the end of the cable I have another rs485 transceiver .
In the experiment I had to cut the cable to two half's of 15m each, and added a board circuit in the middle.
In the circuit I am passing the data on copper wires without anything in the middle (not even repeaters).
The circuit itself would try to 'snub' the data without interfering but my question is about the data channel I just described.

1. when connected to the Board is there a difference if I connect through a connector or just solder them to the board?
2. assuming my copper wires on the board will have a max of 5~10Ω each will it make the line unbalanced/unmatched? if I understand correctly the Z0 impedance of a line is formed mainly by the L/C ratio and I guess my board won't change it much (hopefully).
3. if it does make the line unbalanced - what to expect?

Comment: _I am passing the data on copper wires without anything in the middle (not even repeaters)_ - you make this sound unusual, but it is not.

Comment: _snub without interfering_ sounds deeply suspicious. What does _snub_ mean, and how could it possibly not be considered interference?

Comment: "assuming my copper wires on the board will have a max of 5~10Ω each" 5-10 mΩ perhaps. There's something seriously wrong if the traces on your intermediate board have a series resistance of 5~10 Ω.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, not much difference if you use a connector or solder it.
2. Unbalanced, no, because you are adding series resistance to both data wires, so they stay balanced. Unmatched, yes, as there is a sudden transition of 120 impedance to whatever impedance your wires on the PCB are designed to be. But most likely it does not matter much, as RS485 is supposed to go via multiple devices and even allow for small stubs that interfere with the trunk cable impedance.
3. It won't be unbalanced.